# Splitting a String with conditions

Tags: c#, string

Given a string of:

```
"S1           =F  A1       =T  A2     =T  F3     =F"
```

How can I split it so that the result is an array of strings where the 4 strings ,individual string would look like this:

```
"S1=F"
"A1=T"
"A2=T"
"F3=F"
```

Thank you

Comment: What did you have already tried?

Comment: Just split on whitespace and then join the result in pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try matching all `Name = (T|F)` conditions with *regular expressions* and then get rid of white spaces in the each match with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  .. 

  string source = "S1 \t = F  A1 = T  A2 = T  F3 = F";

  string[] result = Regex
    .Matches(source, @"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*=\s*[TF]")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => string.Concat(match.Value.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))))
    .ToArray();

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
S1=F
A1=T
A2=T
F3=F
```

**Edit:** What's goining on. First part is a regular expression matching:

```
... Regex
    .Matches(source, @"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*=\s*[TF]")
    .OfType<Match>() ...
```

We are trying to find out fragments with a pattern

```
[A-Za-z]      - Letter A..Z or a..z 
[A-Za-z0-9]*  - followed by zero or many letters or digits 
\s*           - zero or more white spaces (spaces, tabulations etc.)
=             - = 
\s*           - zero or more white spaces (spaces, tabulations etc.)
[TF]          - either T or F
```

Second part is *match clearing*: for each `match` found e.g. `S1 \t = F` we want to obtain `"S1=F"` string:

```
... 
.Select(match => string.Concat(match.Value.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))))
.ToArray();
```

We use *Linq* here: for each character in the match we filter out all white spaces (take character `c` if and only if it's not a white space):

```
match.Value.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
```

then combine (`Concat`) filtered characters (`IEnumerable<char>`) of each `match` back to `string` and organize these strings as an array (*materialization*):

```
.Select(match => string.Concat(...))
.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, Would you be able to explain that for me.  I see that you are .Matches anything that is *=T or F.  But can you explain the rest please.

Comment: @7VNT: In the second part we clearing each match (throwing away white spaces and combining filtered `IEnumerable<char>` back to `string`). I've edited the answer, I hope it'll be more crear for you what's going on.